# Laravel and Ajax on a particular div

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel-5

I have a normal javascript datatable with some features due to javascript.
but I also have a delete button for every row to delete data row for which I am using ajax  to refresh the entire datatable but not to the entire page which is successful. but the thing is after deleting one item the entire table looks normatable but not the javascript datatable. and I dont wnat to load the entire page.

datatable :

```
        dataTables.bootstrap.css,

        dataTables.bootstrap.js,

        jquery.dataTables.js
```

Comment: hide the row of the deleted item

Comment: Your question seems to be unclear, what database you are using and what javascript you are using to refresh your table?

Comment: It dosent fit for my query I want to delete but not to hide

Comment: I am just using     $(#div).load(page #div)     to refresh my div of datatable. I am using mysql

Comment: there are some complications of javascript and ajax in laravel

Answer (score 0):

You can either use jquery `remove` the deleted row from DOM or use datatable `reload`.
Removing from DOM is recommended instead of just hiding an element, when the persistent entity representing the element is getting deleted.

Update - To reload the table after removing an element.

`$('.myTable').draw( false );`

Comment: so you mean I just have to reload the scripts or css file used in the code

Comment: but in this case the scripts dos'nt loads I tried to copy the scripts within the div it works and looks good but thats not  the correct way to be done so I am asking for better result.

Comment: <script src="{{asset("lb-sample/plugins/datatables/jquery.dataTables.js")}}" type="text/javascript"></script>     
<script src="{{asset("lb-sample/plugins/datatables/dataTables.bootstrap.js")}}" type="text/javascript"></script>      
<!-- page script -->
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {   
    $("#example1").dataTable();   
    $('#example2').dataTable({   
        "bPaginate": true,   
        "bLengthChange": false,  
        "bFilter": false,  
        "bSort": true,  
        "bInfo": true,  
        "bAutoWidth": false  
    });  
}); 
</script>

Comment: <link href="{{asset("lb-sample/plugins/datatables/dataTables.bootstrap.css")}}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />     
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>   
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>   
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

Comment: Is it possible to load  all the scripts outside the div that loads in the begining

Comment: my scripts are in <head></head>